# prob in implementing mobile view with @media only screen to hide div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, leaflet

I am trying to hide away the div id "tiled-map" when it is on mobile view while all 3 div ids (base-map, overlay-map, tiled-map) in div id "map-wrapper" will be shown in desktop view.

I am using Bootstrap CSS. I don't have any special CSS class for div id "map-wrapper" yet but I forced  its width to 200% on its initial. However, I would like to amend its width to 100% on mobile view -- which I have created a segment of CSS in Bootstrap. I know there's something I did for div class "mobile-hide" is redundant, I was experimenting around with it.

Some partial of the code as shown below.

HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div id="map-wrapper" class="mobile-hide" style="width: 200%; height: 600px; position: relative;">
            <div id="base-map"></div>
            <div id="overlay-map"></div>
            <div id="tiled-map"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #tiled-map {
    visibility: hidden !important;;
    display: none !important;
  }
  .mobile-hide {
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden !important;;
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

---

Updated (Resolved):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="map-wrapper">

            <div id="map1"></div>
            <div id="map2"></div>

            <input id="searchtxt" class="searchtxt" type="text" style="z-index:100; position: relative; top: 20px; left: 70px; border-radius: 5px; width: 250px; font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', Arial; font-weight: 400;  "onkeyup="liveSuggest(this.value)" />
            <div class="dropdown" id="searchResultList" style="z-index:10; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', Arial; font-weight: 400; width: 300px"/ >

        </div>            
            <!-- Pager -->
            <ul class="pager">
                <li class="next">
                </li>
            </ul>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    head {
        background-color: #473731;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #473731;
    }


    #map-wrapper {
         width: 1140px;
         height: 640px;
         position: relative;
         margin: 0 auto;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
        header { display: none; }
        h1 { width: 70% !important; font-weight: 150 !important; }
        #map-wrapper { width: 70% !important; height: 320px !important; }
        #map-wrapper .searchtxt { left: 30px; width: 50px !important; }
        #map1 { width: 100%; }
        #map2 { display: none; }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 799px) {
        h1 { width: 80% !important; font-weight: 200 !important; }
        #map-wrapper { width: 80% !important; height: 480px !important; }
        #map-wrapper .searchtxt { left: 50px; width: 200px !important; }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
        h1 { width: 90% !important; font-weight: 250 !important; }            
        #map-wrapper { width: 90% !important; height: 640px !important; }          
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
        #map-wrapper { width: 90% !important; }           
    }

   /* set the two maps side by side */

    #map1 {
        width: 49.5%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0%;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        border-color: #000000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        z-index: 0;

    }.fullscreen-icon { background-image: url("lib//fullscreen/icon-fullscreen.png"); }
    #map1:-webkit-full-screen { width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; z-index: 99999; }
    #map1:-moz-full-screen { width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; z-index: 99999; }
    #map1:full-screen { width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; z-index: 99999; }
    .leaflet-pseudo-fullscreen { position: fixed !important; width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; z-index: 99999; }

    #map1:hover {
        width: 49.5%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0%;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
          border-radius: 8px;  
          transition: 0.8s;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #888888;
          z-index: 0;
        }


    #map2 {
        width: 49.5%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        border-color: #000000;
        border-radius: 5px;
            z-index: 0;
    }
    #map2:hover {
        width: 49.5%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
          border-radius: 8px;  
          transition: 0.8s;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #888888;
          z-index: 0;
        }
```

Comment: You can use `hidden-xs` class to hide for mobile

Comment: The above code should be hiding the div `#tiled-map` as well as divs with the class 'mobile-hide' associated with them. You should check that you are not overwriting these properties after they are define ie. in another css file

Comment: @Morpheus So I use that class `hidden-xs` on my "base-map" and "overlay-map"? I do understand that: hidden-sm hidden-md = visible-lg, 
hidden-sm hidden-lg = visible-md, 
hidden-md hidden-lg = visible-sm

Comment: @Kinburn101 Could you assist me in this example in jsfiddle or bl.ocks? Much appreciated.

Comment: Kinburn101 is right. It seems to work fine. Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyy88cm6/) Use the handler to re size the output window and check.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fiddle. Note that when you raise the `max-width` in your media query to a size which is larger than the screen you are currently using the items will disapear. When the `max-width` is lowered to a size smaller than the screen it occupies then you will see the red div.

Notice that I set the default styles for the div BEFORE I wrote a media query that would change the visibility. You need to be certain that the media queries you write will overwrite any properties that are already set.

http://jsfiddle.net/rzc7oLtp/1/